How to execute a Spring batch job which can read data from database on regular interval
I'm trying to implement a spring batch application that can read from two tables in mhysql database (using join query) and print the output on console and which can be scheduled to run in an interval say 10 seconds. Although my application is running without any error and also printing the steps in the console but it is not printing any data from the database.
Following is my pom.xml file-
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rcg.m360</groupId>
    <artifactId>crm-scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>m360-crm-scheduler</name>
    <description>Project for the scheduler to get individual ids from Manifest
        DB</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Following is my application.yml file:
    spring:
  application:
    name: m360-crm-scheduler
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        format_sql: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: ${MANIFEST_DB_URL}
    username: ${MANIFEST_DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${MANIFEST_DB_PASSWORD}
    initialize: true

server:
  port: 8081

Here is the BatchConfiguration java class:
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
    @Autowired
    DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);
    
    @Bean
    public Job crmSchedulerJob() {
        logger.info("Job execution started...");
        return new JobBuilder("crmSchedulerJob", jobRepository)
                .start(crmSchedulerStep())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step crmSchedulerStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("crmSchedulerStep", jobRepository)
                .<SchedulerData, SchedulerData>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(crmSchedulerReader())                
                .writer(crmSchedulerWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataSourceConfig.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceConfig.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceConfig.getUserName());
        dataSource.setPassword(dataSourceConfig.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<SchedulerData> crmSchedulerReader() {
        String query = "select gRes.Individual_id, res.Ship_code, res.is_delete from Guest_reservation gRes join Reservation res \r\n"
                + "on gRes.Super_pnr_no=res.Super_pnr_no where res.Sailing_startdate>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), \r\n"
                + "INTERVAL 21 DAY)";
        logger.info("The query is: "+query);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(21);
        
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<SchedulerData>()
                .dataSource(getDataSource())
                .name("crmSchedulerReader")
                .sql(query)
                .beanRowMapper(SchedulerData.class)                
                .build();
    }    
    
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<SchedulerData> crmSchedulerWriter() {
        logger.info("Start of writer method");
        return items -> {
            for (SchedulerData item : items) {
                logger.info("Writing item: " + item);
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Start of perform method");
        crmSchedulerJob();
    }
}

Here is the main application class-
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class M360CrmSchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(M360CrmSchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Here is the DataSourceConfig class -
@Data
@Component
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
}

Here is the DTO SchedulerData class:
public class SchedulerData {
    
    private int individualId;
    private String shipCode;
    private String validityDateTo;
    public SchedulerData(){
        super();
    }
    public SchedulerData(int individualId, String shipCode, String validityDateTo) {
        this.individualId = individualId;
        this.shipCode = shipCode;
        this.validityDateTo = validityDateTo;
    }
    
    public String getValidityDateTo() {
        return validityDateTo;
    }
    
    public void setValidityDateTo(String validityDateTo) {
        this.validityDateTo = validityDateTo;
    }
    
    public int getIndividualId() {
        return individualId;
    }
    
    public void setIndividualId(int individualId) {
        this.individualId = individualId;
    }
    
    public String getShipCode() {
        return shipCode;
    }
    
    public void setShipCode(String shipCode) {
        this.shipCode = shipCode;
    }
}

I have specified the database connection details in the run configurations. I'm getting the following output in the console -
Started M360CrmSchedulerApplication in 3.549 seconds (process running for 4.115)
Start of perform method
Start of perform method
Start of perform method

From the log we can see that the perform method of the BatchConfiguration class is executing every 10 seconds but the job method is not executing as the logger statement in the job method is not printed. I'm not able to find why the control is not going to the job method, any help on this will be highly appreciated.

In your code is that the perform method is not actually triggering the execution of the Spring Batch job. Instead, it is merely calling the method that defines the job (crmSchedulerJob) without actually running it.
If you adapt your perform method like below then it should work.
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
.
.
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void perform() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Start of perform method");
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .toJobParameters();

    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(crmSchedulerJob(), jobParameters);
    logger.info("Job Execution Status: " + jobExecution.getStatus());
}

Note: If you did not add table for Spring batch job then please do create those by executing this queries

I Have done the changes you suggested but after running it getting the following error-      Started M360CrmSchedulerApplication in 3.542 seconds (process running for 4.05)
2024-06-18T10:00:32.927+05:30 ERROR 20084 --- [m360-crm-scheduler] [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME
FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
WHERE JOB_NAME = ?
and JOB_KEY = ?]

This is in spite of the fact that the same join query is running in mysql workbench and showing results.

This is resolved after manually running the queries to create Spring batch metadata tables from here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql

yes, you need to add those tables :) and please accept the answer if it helped
